# Using pip to install MySQLdb error on Mac OS X 10.12

Tags: mysql, django, macos, python-2.7

I am current using Mac OS X 10.12.I am trying to install MySQLdb but kept getting these error.

When I running sudo pip install MySQLdb,the error message is:

```
Collecting MySQL-python
Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 233kB/s 
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/tmp/pip-build-m1bhp0l0/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
    from setup_posix import get_config
  File "/private/tmp/pip-build-m1bhp0l0/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-m1bhp0l0/MySQL-python/
```

and then I try to download MySQL-python-1.2.4b4, and use that to directly running setup.py.Then I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/phil/Downloads/MySQL-python-1.2.4b4 2/setup.py", line 18, in <module>
metadata, options = get_config()
File "/Users/phil/Downloads/MySQL-python-1.2.4b4 2/setup_posix.py", line 32, in get_config
metadata, options = get_metadata_and_options()
File "/Users/phil/Downloads/MySQL-python-1.2.4b4 2/setup_common.py", line 12, in get_metadata_and_options
metadata = dict(config.items('metadata'))
   File"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 642, in items
raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'metadata'
```

Tried lots of solutions out there.Still got lots of errors.
Plz help here.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the MySQL-python package does not [currently support Python 3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5).

You could use another mysql package like [mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) which is a fork of MySQL-python, supports Python 3 and has worked well for me:

```
 sudo pip install mysqlclient
```

Or if you still need to use MySQL-python you could try installing it in Python 2.7 and use that for development:

```
 sudo pip2 install MySQL-python
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do i check i am running under python3 or 2......
I think i installed both....

Comment: Also I install mysqlclient successfully.but not quite know what the next step......

Comment: @honesty1997 http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/django/4933/database-setup/17418/mysql-mariadb#t=201610220756400626975

Comment: In the terminal, you can write `python -V` to check which is the default version of python you're using. You can always use `python3` or `python2` to make sure you're using the right version. Also, check which version of python pip is using running this command `pip -V`. Again, you can use `pip3` or `pip2` to make sure you're using the one you want.

Comment: About the next step. It depends on what you want to do and what the current state of your mysql installation. The link @lxer provides is very thorough

Comment: In my experience mysqlclient works fine with Python 2.7. I used it on a fresh install of a project that formerly used MySQL-Python (which appears to be moribund with no updates for years).